Typehints on keys of an inferred generic param
Task
I'm building an utility with following interface:
interface F<M extends Record<string, Function>> {
  (
    listeners: M, 
    options: { filter: e => boolean }
  ): void
}

Special thing here is filter option, which will receive events from all provided listeners.
I want type of e parameter to depend on provided listeners:
f({
  e1: (e: E1) => {}
}, {
  filter: e => {} // <= `e` should be of type `E1`
})

f({
  e1: (e: E1) => {},
  e2: (e: E2) => {}
}, {
  filter: e => {} // <= `e` should be of type `E1 | E2`
})

Solution
I found a way to do this:
interface F<T> {
  <E extends keyof T>(
    listeners: Pick<T, E>, 
    options: { filter: (e: Arg<T[E]>) => boolean }
  ): void
}

It does exactly what I want with parameter of filter func, and it correctly applies constraints to listeners, forbidding to add keys not defined in T.
Problem
It's just one little issue – typescript can't hint available keys for listeners object.
I.e., if I declare let f: F<{ e1: Function, e2: Function }> and do f({ ... }) and ctrl+space – it shows a whole bunch of random stuff, instead of just e1 and e2.
I understand that it's expected behavior with this implementation. TS can't know about available options, because, basically, it's me who defines type of listeners, TS can only test it then against constraint of keyof T.
But is it possible, by any chance, to achieve typehints here? While not losing neither proper inference of parameter of filter cb, nor keys validation of listeners param?
I played around in a sandbox, yet all options I tried lack one or another feature I want.

I could imagine changing your code to this version but I don't know if that suits your needs. It's really difficult to get error behavior to meet specific requirements, because once you start calling the function incorrectly, the type checker is free to have it fail in all kinds of ways. How should we proceed here?

@jcalz so this version gives "value not assignable to type never" instead of "key does not exist in type"? Well, it's less "user-friendly", but with hints actually working – not a big of a deal, I think. I will accept this as correct answer.

You can't have arbitrary control over exactly how TypeScript reports errors or makes IntelliSense suggestions. There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#23689 to allow custom error messages. I don't think there's any feature request to allow custom IntelliSense suggestions, but neither feature is available anyway. At some point you'll likely need to find an approach that works for your most important use cases and then give up on some less important ones.
One possible approach you didn't mention exploring above looks like:
interface F<T> {
    <M extends T & Record<Exclude<keyof M, keyof T>, never>>(
        map: M, opts: OptsFromMap<M>
    ): void
}

Since M is generic, merely constraining it to T wouldn't prevent excess properties. You're allowed to add properties when extending types.  Indeed you're really always allowed to add excess properties, even for non-generics. It's just that excess property checking makes it seem as though you sometimes can't.
The only way to get behavior like excess property checking for generics is to constrain the generic so that excess properties get constrained to the impossible never type. (hence Record<Exclude<keyof M, keyof T>, never>.) That way you're mostly guaranteed an error if you add an excess property. The error will not say "excess properties aren't allowed". It will say "this property isn't never".  We can change that error message to something like "this property isn't ExcessPropertyErrorType" or some custom-named thing:
interface ExcessPropertyErrorType {
    err: never;
}

interface F<T> {
    <M extends T & Record<Exclude<keyof M, keyof T>, ExcessPropertyErrorType>>(
        map: M, opts: OptsFromMap<M>
    ): void
}

but it's not necessarily a better user experience.
Let's test it out:
declare let f: F<EventsMap>
f({ e1: e => e, }, { option: x => x })
f({ e1: e => e, e2: e => e, }, { option: x => x })
f({ e1: e => e, foo: e => e, }, { option: x => x }); // error!
//              ~~~  ~

Looks good, mostly. You get the expected IntelliSense, and the inferred types are correct, and you get an error on the excess property itself. The wording of the error message isn't amazing, but it's as good as you can get for generic extensions.
Playground link to code
